# Should I use sqlite?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

In my app i want to add a new feature that consist in having a list of object's bought by the user. So, when the user buy something he add's that object to the list. Later, if he starts the app again,there should be all the items added in the list.

The object will have some parameters (name, bought date, price, etc etc). My question is: is this a case to use **sqlite**?

If yes, In the activity with the list of the objects, everytime the activity starts I will have to load the table from *database*?

Comment: @eldjon yeah, my mistake. Already edited

Comment: @niarb .... If your query is resolved ! ... Accept any one of the answers that helped ! ( Check the green arrow in the answer )... so others also could refer this post ... Happy Coding !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Should I use sqlite?**

*Well, it depends on your preference and the scenario,*

- If you are using a `webserver` and updating the `webserver`, no need
  to use a `sqlite` since you can ping a query to server and show the
  objects for the list
- If you are not using a `webserver` you can use `Sqlite` for this
  scenario since you can perform all the
  `CRUD(Create,Read,Update,Delete)` operations for the `Sqlite`

---

***[Advantages and disadvantages of using SQlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10329842/why-to-use-sqlite-database-in-android)***

Pros:

- If your application gets closed the in memory data will be lost, but after that you will be able to restore the state from the database if you have one
- Especially for the case of complex calculations it is good to store the result once in the database and not recalculate it multiple times on demand
- The database will untie your UI from the internet connection and thus you will be able to display results even if there is not internet connection
- Using database you will be able to fetch the updated data from a background service, without impacting your UI
- Organizing your data in database usually makes it a lot easier to manage all the application data.

Cons:

- Adding database will require a bit of additional effort on your side

---

**Sinple Line** :: ***Go for Sqlite solution***

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your first question is "yes".  The answer to the second is, also, "yes".